# mysql insert record not immediately available, select count(*) doesn't see it right away

Tags: php, mysql

In my php code, I have a Mysql query:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
```

to see if the record already exists, then if it doesn't exist I do an:

```
INSERT INTO <etc>
```

But if someone hits reload with a second or so, the `SELECT COUNT(*)` doesn't see the inserted record.

```
$ssql="SELECT COUNT(*) as counts FROM `points`  WHERE `username` LIKE '".$lusername."' AND description LIKE '".$desc."' AND `info` LIKE '".$key."' AND `date` LIKE '".$today."'";  
$result = mysql_query($ssql);  
$row=mysql_fetch_array($result);  
if ($row['counts']==0) // no points for this design before  
    {  
    $isql="INSERT INTO `points` (`datetime`,`username`,`ip`,`description`,`points`,`info`, `date`,`uri`) ";  
    $isql=$isql."VALUES ('".date("Y-m-d H:i:s")."','".$lusername."',";  
    $isql=$isql."'".$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']."','".$desc."','".$points."',";  
    $isql=$isql."'".$key."','".$today."','".$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']."')";  
    $iresult = mysql_query($isql);  
    return(true);  
    }  
else  
    return(false);
```

I was using MyISAM database type

Comment: And what errors you get? If no error no problem,

Comment: Hi, Have you selected a default table? What if you try `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "DATABASE_NAME"`?
Also, you say that it doesn't work within a few seconds. Does it ever work? Even after a minute or so?

Comment: Yes it works fine, the insert works.   I can replicate it by hitting reload on the browser.  The record is there, duplicated.  If I let the page load instead of hitting reload over and over it doesn't create a duplicate record.  Like there's it on on a queue to be written?

Comment: Can you post your if statement along with your actual select?

Comment: Original updated with code.

Comment: Just thought I will add a cookie in the header and check for it... mysql vs browser cookie ... who will win?

Comment: Just a fyi, adding a index to the points database fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of running two seperate queries just use [`REPLACE INTO`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/replace.html).

From the documentation:

> REPLACE works exactly like INSERT, except that if an old row in the table has the same value as a new row for a PRIMARY KEY or a UNIQUE index, the old row is deleted before the new row is inserted.

For example if your key field is `id` then:

```
REPLACE INTO my_table SET id = 4 AND other_field = 'foobar'
```

will insert if there is no record with id 4, or if there is then it will replace the other_field value with foobar.

Comment: I can't introduce a unique or primary index.  The use of the database won't allow (plus I have over a million records in this table).

Comment: @Shawn your comment doesn't make much sense to me. There should be no need to check before inserting.